# Почему не появляется alert?

Tags: javascript, html, всплывающее-окно

У меня есть код:

```js
function transcript(){
  var str = document.getElementById('deutch_text').value;
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="transcript();">
  <input type="text" id="deutch_text" placeholder="Текст на немецком">
  <input type="text" id="russian_text" placeholder="Текст на русском" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="Транскрибировать">
</form>
```

По идее при нажатии кнопки должен появляться текст, который я ввёл, но он не появляется. Почему?

Comment: копка 'Транскрибировать' должна быть `type="submit"`

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте элементу `input` атрибут `type="submit`.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function transcript() {
      var str = document.getElementById('deutch_text').value;
      alert(str);

    }
  </script>
  <form onsubmit="transcript();">
    <input type="text" id="deutch_text" placeholder="Текст на немецком">
    <input type="text" id="russian_text" placeholder="Текст на русском" disabled>
    <input type="submit" value="Транскрибировать">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById('deutch_text').value;
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Транскриптор</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="deutch_text" placeholder="Текст на немецком">
    <input type="text" id="russian_text" placeholder="Текст на русском" disabled>
    <input type="submit" value="Транскрибировать">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```